# Stored procedure in mysql strange behaviour

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

This stored procedure is taking care of material reservations. The basic idea is that it checks how much of THIS material are already hired and if there are still materials in stock i will insert a new order. If there is already a reservation for this material for this reservation id i am updating the amount.

Maybe im doing something wrong but when i try to add a new reservation it works. The update NEVER works and when there is already a reservation for an specif material id it's not possible to rent it with another reservation id.

I give you an example:

```
CALL aantal_besch_mat_van_tot('2007-03-13','2007-03-14',15,6,50,'procedure test lol');
```

Ok so this works but when i execute  it again the amount 50 should go to 50 + previous so it should be 100 it never updates.

Also when you would hire the same material with another reservation id it's not working.
example:

```
CALL aantal_besch_mat_van_tot('2007-03-13','2007-03-14',15,7,50,'Im hiring this material');
```

That is also not working.

I already printed out al value's and there getting the right amount.

Here you can find my stored procedure code:

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fabiola`.`aantal_besch_mat_van_tot`(IN `p_datum_van` date,IN `p_datum_tot` date,IN `p_mat_id` int, IN `p_res_id` int, IN `p_nodig` int, IN `p_mat_opmerking` VARCHAR(255))

BEGIN
    DECLARE aantal INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE tot  INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE upda INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE nieuwa INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE voriga INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE test INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE res_van datetime;
    DECLARE res_tot datetime;

    -- Overeenkomstige data selecteren
    SELECT r.incheckdatum, r.uitcheckdatum FROM reservaties r
    WHERE r.id = p_res_id
    INTO res_van, res_tot;

        SELECT mpr.aantal FROM materialen_per_reservatie mpr
        WHERE mpr.materialen_id = p_mat_id AND
            (
            (p_datum_van >= mpr.datum_van AND p_datum_tot <= mpr.datum_tot) -- overlap: binnen
            OR (p_datum_van <= mpr.datum_van AND p_datum_tot >= mpr.datum_van) -- overlap: voor+in
            OR (p_datum_van <= mpr.datum_tot AND p_datum_tot >= mpr.datum_tot) -- overlap: na+in
            OR (p_datum_van <= mpr.datum_van AND p_datum_tot >= mpr.datum_tot) -- overlap:omsluitend
            )
        INTO aantal;

        -- The total amount of materials
        SELECT m.aantal_beschikbaar FROM materialen m
        WHERE m.id = p_mat_id
        INTO tot;
        -- The test variable is holding the amount of materials that's still available
        SELECT tot-aantal INTO test;
        -- Checking if im not ordering more then there is available
        IF p_nodig < test THEN
            -- Checking if this material is already hired from this reservation id
            SELECT mpra.id, mpra.aantal FROM materialen_per_reservatie mpra
            WHERE (mpra.reservaties_id = p_res_id
            AND   mpra.materialen_id = p_mat_id) INTO upda, voriga;
            -- if voriga is bigger then zero it means that there is already an reservatie for this material for this reservation so im not inserting but updating
            IF voriga > 0 THEN
                -- Selecting the previous amount and add it with the p_nodig amount
                SELECT voriga+p_nodig INTO nieuwa;
                UPDATE materialen_per_reservatie SET materialen_per_reservatie.aantal = nieuwa WHERE reservaties_id = p_res_id AND materialen_id = p_mat_id;
            ELSE
                -- There is no reservation for this material with this reservation id so i my insert a new row
                INSERT INTO materialen_per_reservatie(reservaties_id, materialen_id, aantal, effectief_gebruikt, opmerking, datum_van, datum_tot) VALUES (p_res_id, p_mat_id, p_nodig, p_nodig, p_mat_opmerking, p_datum_van, p_datum_tot);
            END IF;
        END IF;
END$$
```

I tested out both INSERT / UPDATE query's separate and they are working.

Comment: what is the isolation level? have you tried to put it in a transaction?

Comment: I'm sorry that was a typo. i'm already using the '' for the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are the quotes around your date values?

Try this:

```
call aantal_besch_mat_van_tot('2007-03-13', '2007-03-14', 15, 6, 50, 'Im hiring this material');
```

Note dates are like `'2007-03-13'`, not `2007-03-13`, which is literally the number `1991` (ie 2007 - 3 - 13 = 1991)

Comment: I'm sorry that was a typo. i'm already using the one you'r saying above in mysql